# MySQL relationship loop

Tags: php, mysql

Got a small relational problem with a project I'm working on, I've tried googling the answer, but not sure what terminology to use to find my answer Lol

The problem to be solved:

A user can have many photos, and one of these photos can be a profile photo, but only one.

So for example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(25) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE photo (
    ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_ID Int NOT NULL,
    imgpath varchar(260) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ID) REFERENCES user (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE table userprofphoto (
    user_ID Int NOT NULL,
    photo_ID Int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (photo_ID) REFERENCES photo (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ID) REFERENCES user (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

So a query to get the users profile photo would be:

```
SELECT imgpath FROM photo WHERE photo_ID=(SELECT photo_ID FROM userprofphoto WHERE user_ID=:userid LIMIT 1)
```

This works, but it creates a relational loop. Should/Could I fix this?

I did think about removing the `user_ID` from the `userprofphoto` table, but then this would increase the query length:

```
SELECT imgpath FROM photo
LEFT JOIN userprofphoto ON userprofphoto.photo_ID=photo.ID
WHERE photo.user_ID=:user_id
```

Any help appreciated :D

Comment: You don't have any loop in your design though.

Comment: It does ... Cos userprofphoto has FK user.ID and FK photo.ID, and photo has FK user.ID

Comment: That's 2 paths (from `userprofphoto` to `user`), not a loop.

Comment: I think your overall design is okay. I don't see any "LOOP" there. Also, you said (not exact words, paraphrase) that each user can only have 1 profile photo. So I suggest under userprofphoto, make user_ID unique.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a loop ... Starting to doubt myself a little now, which I don't like Lol :s ... There is a path from photo -> user, a path from userprofphoto -> photo and userprofphoto -> user ... So it's like a little love triangle

Comment: @user3139907 It's a loop if you think of the constraints as non-directional. If you try though to start from (any) table and move through the `->` paths, you can't return to where you started.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2wgd7ar/8

Answer (score 1):

Your first query does not make sense because `imgpath` is only in `photos` in your design.  (By the way, I generally prefer to give tables plural names rather than singular.  It helps to avoid conflicts with reserved words.)

One problem with your design is that the table `userprofphoto` has no constraint on it.  So a user can have multiple profile photos.  This is easily fixed by adding a unique constraint or unique index on the field `user_ID` in the table.

Other than this minor tweak, your design is fine.  There are two other approaches.

One is to have a flag in the `photo` table that specifies that a photo is used for the profile.  This is very hard to maintain in MySQL.  Other databases have functionality that makes this easier.

However, the best solution may be to eliminate the `userprofphoto` table entirely and just add a column to `user`.  This automatically enforces the constraint of there only being one profile photo.  Of course, if you later decide to remove this limitation, then you need to reintroduce the `userprofphoto` table.

You might also want a constraint that the user actually owns the profile photo.  That requires a trigger to implement in MySQL.  You can probably handle this in the logic that adds and modifies the profile photo.

With this structure, your query would be:

```
SELECT imgpath
FROM users u join
     photos p
     ON u.profile_photo_ID = p.photo_ID;
WHERE u.user_ID = :user_id;
```

Comment: Yep ... Noticed my wrong query Lol ... changed it :D Also, cheers for the unique index idea

Comment: @Gordon if we add a `profile_photo_id` column to `user`, we'll then have a loop in the foreign key references. And since MySQL has not implemented deferred constraints, that would be really hard to manage.

Comment: @ypercube . . . You can add it afterwards with a separate `alter table` statement (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e091d).

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. The real problems will come when you try to insert rows.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce the requirements you mention, I would use the following design:

- add a unique (or primary key) constraint on the profile table so every user has only one profile photo
- change the two foreign key constraints from the profile table to one. With your current design, you could end with a profile photo of a user that is attached to a different user.

(I'd also not use the `ID` as name but `user_ID`, `photo_ID`, etc everywhere):

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE photo (
    photo_ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_ID Int NOT NULL,
    imgpath varchar(260) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (user_ID, photo_ID),          -- this is is needed for the FK below
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ID) 
      REFERENCES user (user_ID) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE table userprofphoto (
    user_ID Int NOT NULL,
    photo_ID Int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_ID),         -- only one profile photo per user
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ID, photo_ID) 
      REFERENCES photo (user_ID, photo_ID) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `photo_ID` from `userprofphoto` and add one column `profile_photo` on table `photo` the value will be 1/0 make add `profile_photo=1` in your where condition.

When user select the profile photo you just update profile_photo=1, in this case you have to do two update first update to `set profile_photo=0 where profile_photo=1` second update will be set `set profile_photo=1 where ID=[PHPTO_ID]`